funny behavior with a scrolling table
==== Final Edit ====
I have the page working as best as I can get it. None of the answers here were definitive. I just worked at it until it worked. I thank everyone who tried to help, as the effort itself is worthy of acknowledgement.
The text below is modified to show my solution to the problem.
==================
In my experience I have found that there is no one size fits all when it comes to CSS scrolling tables. Every time I implement them I have to create a new way to do it because the previous ways didn't work. Such is the case this time as well.
Here is the CSS that works:
table {             border:                 none;
                    border-spacing:         0;
                    border-collapse:        separate;
                    table-layout:           fixed;
    }

/* freeze panes */
/* rows 1-3 */
thead {             position:               sticky;
                    top:                    0;
                    min-height:             35pt;
                    height:                 35pt;
                    z-index:                50;
                    background-color:       White;
    }

/* columns */
/* col 1 */
.posfixleft {       position:               sticky;
                    top:                    0;
                    left:                   0;
                    height:                 12pt;
                    width:                  35pt;
                    z-index:                20;
                    background-color:       White;
    }

Here is the changes to the HTML:
<TABLE style='width: 1917pt;'>
 <COL style='width:35pt'>
 <COL span=21 style='width:54pt'>
 <COL style='width:71pt'>
 <COL span=2 style='width:54pt'>
 <COL style='width:56pt'>
 <COL span=2 style='width:54pt'>
 <COL style='width:81pt'>
 <COL span=2 style='width:54pt'>
 <COL style='width:91pt'>
 <COL span=2 style='width:54pt'>
 <COL style='width:12pt'>
 <THEAD>
 <TR style='height: 15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center toprightleft' style='width: 35pt'>level</TD>
  <TD colspan=18 class='bold center topright' style='width: 972pt'>hbox5</TD>
  <TD colspan=15 class='bold center topright' style='width: 874pt'>yasc hbox</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr'></TD>
 </TR>

 </THEAD>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center rightleft' style='width:35pt'>1</TD>

 </TR>
</TABLE>

There are many columns and many rows, so I am showing only the code that is pertinent to the CSS. I have uploaded the page to my website so you can see what it contains and view the source in its entirety: https://wayneca.neocities.org/Sokoban/hbox-yasc.html


body {              /*margin:                   0;*/
                    border:                 none;
                    font-family:            Tahoma, sans-serif;
                    font-size:              12.0pt;
                    vertical-align:         bottom;
                    white-space:            nowrap;
                    color:                  Black;
    }

table {             border:                 none;
                    border-spacing:         0;
                    border-collapse:        separate;
                    table-layout:           fixed;
    }

/* freeze panes */
/* rows 1-3 */
thead {             position:               sticky;
                    top:                    0;
                    min-height:             35pt;
                    height:                 35pt;
                    z-index:                50;
                    background-color:       White;
    }

/* columns */
/* col 1 */
.posfixleft {       position:               sticky;
                    top:                    0;
                    left:                   0;
                    height:                 12pt;
                    width:                  35pt;
                    z-index:                20;
                    background-color:       White;
    }

td {                padding-top:    1px;
                    padding-right:  1px;
                    padding-left:   1px;
                    color:          Black;
    }
<TABLE style='width: 1917pt;'>
 <COL style='width:35pt'>
 <COL span=21 style='width:54pt'>
 <COL style='width:71pt'>
 <COL span=2 style='width:54pt'>
 <COL style='width:56pt'>
 <COL span=2 style='width:54pt'>
 <COL style='width:81pt'>
 <COL span=2 style='width:54pt'>
 <COL style='width:91pt'>
 <COL span=2 style='width:54pt'>
 <COL style='width:12pt'>
 <THEAD>
 <TR style='height: 15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center toprightleft' style='width: 35pt'>level</TD>
  <TD colspan=18 class='bold center topright' style='width: 972pt'>hbox5</TD>
  <TD colspan=15 class='bold center topright' style='width: 874pt'>yasc hbox</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr'></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center rightleft' style='width: 35pt'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'>moves</TD>
  <TD class='bold center right' style='width: 54pt'>pushes</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'>moves</TD>
  <TD class='bold center right' style='width: 54pt'>pushes</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'>moves</TD>
  <TD class='bold center right' style='width: 54pt'>pushes</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'>moves</TD>
  <TD class='bold center right' style='width: 54pt'>pushes</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'>moves</TD>
  <TD class='bold center right' style='width: 54pt'>pushes</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'>moves</TD>
  <TD class='bold center right' style='width: 54pt'>pushes</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'>moves</TD>
  <TD class='bold center right' style='width: 54pt'>pushes</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 71pt'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'>moves</TD>
  <TD class='bold center right' style='width: 54pt'>pushes</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 56pt'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'>moves</TD>
  <TD class='bold center right' style='width: 54pt'>pushes</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 81pt'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'>moves</TD>
  <TD class='bold center right' style='width: 54pt'>pushes</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 91pt'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 54pt'>moves</TD>
  <TD class='bold center right' style='width: 54pt'>pushes</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 12pt'></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center bottomrightleft' style='width: 35pt'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center bottom' style='width: 54pt'>0</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='bold center bottomright' style='width: 108pt'>abort reason</TD>
  <TD class='bold center bottom' style='width: 54pt'>1</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='bold center bottomright' style='width: 108pt'>abort reason</TD>
  <TD class='bold center bottom' style='width: 54pt'>2</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='bold center bottomright' style='width: 108pt'>abort reason</TD>
  <TD class='bold center bottom' style='width: 54pt'>3</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='bold center bottomright' style='width: 108pt'>abort reason</TD>
  <TD class='bold center bottom' style='width: 54pt'>4</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='bold center bottomright' style='width: 108pt'>abort reason</TD>
  <TD class='bold center bottom' style='width: 54pt'>5</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='bold center bottomright' style='width: 108pt'>abort reason</TD>
  <TD class='bold center bottom' style='width: 54pt'>QUICK</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='bold center bottomright' style='width: 108pt'>abort reason</TD>
  <TD class='bold center bottom' style='width: 71pt'>EFFICIENT</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='bold center bottomright' style='width: 108pt'>abort reason</TD>
  <TD class='bold center bottom' style='width: 56pt'>QUICK+</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='bold center bottomright' style='width: 108pt'>abort reason</TD>
  <TD class='bold center bottom' style='width: 81pt'>EFFICIENT+</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='bold center bottomright' style='width: 108pt'>abort reason</TD>
  <TD class='bold center bottom' style='width: 91pt'>EFFICIENT++</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='bold center bottomright' style='width: 108pt'>abort reason</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width: 12pt'></TD>
 </TR>
 </THEAD>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center rightleft' style='width:35pt'>1</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen' style='width:54pt'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center' style='width:54pt'>383</TD>
  <TD class='center right' style='width:54pt'>101</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen' style='width:54pt'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center' style='width:54pt'>428</TD>
  <TD class='center right' style='width:54pt'>101</TD>
  <TD class='center' style='width:54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='center' style='width:54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='center right' style='width:54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen' style='width:54pt'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center' style='width:54pt'>297</TD>
  <TD class='center right' style='width:54pt'>101</TD>
  <TD class='center' style='width:54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='center' style='width:54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='center right' style='width:54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='center' style='width:54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='center' style='width:54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='center right' style='width:54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen' style='width:54pt'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center' style='width:54pt'>383</TD>
  <TD class='center right' style='width:54pt'>101</TD>
  <TD class='center' style='width:71pt'></TD>
  <TD class='center' style='width:54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='center right' style='width:54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen' style='width:56pt'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center' style='width:54pt'>297</TD>
  <TD class='center right' style='width:54pt'>101</TD>
  <TD class='center' style='width:81pt'></TD>
  <TD class='center' style='width:54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='center right' style='width:54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='center' style='width:91pt'></TD>
  <TD class='center' style='width:54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='center right' style='width:54pt'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr' style='width:12pt'></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center rightleft'>2</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>869</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>167</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>957</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>171</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>834</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>159</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>869</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>167</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>834</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>159</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr'></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center rightleft'>3</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>730</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>150</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>672</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>148</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>666</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>150</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>730</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>150</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>666</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>150</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr'></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center rightleft'>4</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1554</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>419</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1458</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>403</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1322</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>395</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1554</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>419</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1322</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>395</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr'></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center rightleft'>5</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>869</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>171</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>753</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>189</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>881</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>189</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>869</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>171</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>881</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>189</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr'></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center rightleft'>6</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>544</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>112</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>494</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>112</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>492</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>128</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>544</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>112</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>492</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>128</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr'></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center rightleft'>7</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>653</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>144</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>665</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>124</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>597</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>172</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>653</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>144</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>597</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>172</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr'></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center rightleft'>8</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1438</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>286</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1776</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>282</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1260</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>290</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1438</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>286</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr'></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center rightleft'>9</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1008</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>279</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1088</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>281</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>944</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>277</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1008</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>279</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>944</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>277</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr'></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center rightleft'>10</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr'></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center rightleft'>11</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr'></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center rightleft'>12</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>2133</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>272</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>2257</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>288</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1831</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>268</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>2133</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>272</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1831</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>268</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr'></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center rightleft'>13</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1894</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>298</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1894</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>298</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr'></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center rightleft'>14</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='indianred'>Unsolved</TD>
  <TD colspan=2 class='center right'>time limit</TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr'></TD>
 </TR>
 <TR style='height:15.0pt'>
  <TD class='posfixleft bold center rightleft'>15</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1436</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>278</TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1520</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>278</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1370</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>292</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1436</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>278</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='darkolivegreen'>Solved</TD>
  <TD class='center'>1370</TD>
  <TD class='center right'>292</TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center'></TD>
  <TD class='center right'></TD>
  <TD class='bold center nobrdr'></TD>
 </TR>
</TABLE>




Post code as a [mcve] (hint: click the brackets button <>).

The problem with that is, the table has 34 columns (first one frozen) and 93 rows (first 3 frozen). To reproduce the issue here with minimum code would require a minimum of 21 columns (to allow for horizontal scroll) and a minimum of 33 rows (to allow for vertical scroll). And that's on my monitor (1920 x 1080 resolution and using 125% view) in FireFox. I can't say what other browsers and resolutions may require. That's why I provided links to the pages. It may be much, but you are welcome to copy the page code and work on it on your computer.

Go to this answer. It's a <table>  that has 20 vertical scrolling columns and each end has a sticky column. More importantly it has it's on scrollbar only covers the scrolling portion of the <table> and not the two sticky columns. Also there are no side effects like scrollbars on the body or :root. Also it's responsive.

I looked at that answer. If I used flex it would be a good answer, but I don't use flex. I have gotten most of the issue solved, but the table layout (the way the text in the cells looks) is still wrong and I can't figure out how to fix it (plus the top 3 rows don't scroll horizontally). I have uploaded a new version of the #2 page reflecting these changes.

Please post solutions below as answer, not into the question.

That tells me that you haven't really read the answer (or understood it?). There's one flexbox but it's <main>. It's purpose is to keep the <table> perfectly in viewport. It is not a flex layout as far as the <table> is concerned. BTW I have no idea how the text looks wrong 1. Your post isn't a [mcve] (which in your case is definitely required). 2. Links are not a reliable source, websites come and go, can you guarantee that that link will still exist in the next couple of years so this question will still be helpful? 3. All your efforts have hindered us in assisting you.

The table is very large. The only minimally reproducible version is the entire table. The page as it exists now is on the website and will be there for as long as my website exists (which will be at least until I die). I will try to create a smaller version. Also, the "final result" is not exactly what I am after. I settled for having the body with no margins to get rid of the problems of shifting top and left when scrolling down or right (respectively) and not being able to get the scrollbars above and to the left of the bottom and right margins of the viewport.

OK, I have added a snippet with the first 15 rows of the table (that was the minimum I could do to get a vertical scrollbar to show up in the snippet editor). I removed the 0 margin on the body so you can see what it looks like with the 3-pixel margin in place. Scroll right and down to see the table shift when you scroll. Notice the scrollbars are at the right and bottom instead of inset for the right and bottom margins.

You can place the <table> inside a <div class="table-container">, which will give you more flexibility.
Add this CSS:
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

If that's not it, please clarify how you would like the scroll bars to be.

The bootstrap css for .table-responsive might be a better solution. .table-responsive {     display: block;     width: 100%;     overflow-x: auto;     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; }

I have other pages using scrollable tables. Mostly they are vertical scroll only, but there is one that is both vertical and horizontal. However, that one is too different from the others for me to use it. I tried already, which is what screwed it up to begin with.

One example I have is this page: https://wayneca.neocities.org/Sokoban/YASS.html

If you scroll the page I'm working on, you'll notice that the top and left sides of the table scroll down (and right) because the scrollbars are attached to the viewport, not the table. I want the scrollbars attached to the table to stop this from happening. I also want the bottom and right borders of the table to be within the viewport, not offscreen.

OK, changing the table's width and height to 100vw and 100vh corrected where the edges of the table occur, but the scrollbars are still being attached to the viewport, not the table.
